# jplayer control box autohide into div

Tags: jquery, css, jplayer

I work with [Jplayer](http://jplayer.org/)(jquery video player plugin). i custom control box(play/pause ...) for show when mouse rollover in `jp-jplayer div` with this:

```
autohide: {
    restored: true, fadeIn:500,
},
```

this worked and when i mouse over in `jp-jplayer div`, control box show in Outside of this div(bottom). now i need to show control box into `jp-jplayer div`, not outside this div. How to show control box into `div`?

Online Example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/JEEqj/) (`in example control box is hide and after mouseover u see panel outside div`)

Answer (score 1):

You achieve this simply with CSS by adding a negative `margin-top` to the class `.jp-interface`

E.g.

```
div.jp-interface {
   margin-top:-88px;
}
```